# Where to find Catholic Church records for the early 1800s Middlesex, England?

Tags: england, records, catholic-church

I need to find Catholic church records for the time period between 1830 and 1860 St Giles & Bloomsbury, Middlesex and St Andrews, Middlesex.

I have tried to look on Ancestry and on FindMyPast but they don't seem to have any of the records that I need. I have and can try to contact the individual parishes but some have been built after that and maybe they don't know where the earlier records are.

Answer (score 4):

Westminster Diocesan Archives  are based in Kensington and have a comprehensive guide to the sacramental registers they hold available through the Family History pages of their website.
https://rcdow.org.uk/diocese/archives/

Answer (score 3):

The generally accepted source for information about what Roman Catholic parishes were where and when in England (and ?) is

> "Catholic Missions & Registers 1700-1880", vol. 1-6;
>
> *Author*: Michael Gandy
>
> *Published* London : Michael Gandy, 1993

I don't, however, have access to any of the volumes for that part of the world.

Online information is generally to be found in the GENUKI system. See the [GENUKI Gazetteer](https://www.genuki.org.uk/big/Gazetteer/). There are pages for [Holborn St. Andrew](https://www.genuki.org.uk/node/62911), [St. Giles In The Fields](https://www.genuki.org.uk/node/62948) and [Bloomsbury](https://www.genuki.org.uk/node/62872), which may or may not be the (Anglican) parishes that you need. None look especially fruitful, with only 2 RC parishes listed - founded in 1873 and 1853. You are therefore probably going to need to look wider afield in the [GENUKI pages for Middlesex](https://www.genuki.org.uk/big/eng/MDX/) to see what RC churches are in the surrounding areas. I don't know of any simple way of finding references to RC churches other than checking each (Anglican) parish manually. I think it's just hard work with maps and the gazetteer.

Comment: The WorldCat record for _Catholic Missions & Registers_ is [here](https://www.worldcat.org/title/catholic-missions-and-registers-1700-1880/oclc/60755785), in case OP wants to see whether there is a copy in a library near them.